# vagrant-share plugin installation error -- fog-core gem mismatch

Tags: ruby, bundler, fog, vagrant-plugin, vagrant-share

I'm learning Vagrant's vagrant-share plugin and ran into a Bundler error:

"conflicting dependencies fog-core (~> 1.43.0) and fog-core (= 1.45.0). activated fog-core-1.45.0 which does not match conflicting dependency (~> 1.43.0)."

I've uninstalled fog-core and all dependent gems, then reinstalled fog-core 1.43.0, yet the error msg persists.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same error on Ubuntu after I had installed vagrant by doing `sudo apt install vagrant`. Turns out that installs a version of vagrant that is too old, so I had to uninstall it, download `vagrant_2.2.10_linux_amd64.zip`, unzip it, and do a `sudo mv vagrant /usr/bin`. That got rid of the fog-core errors.